# Search Data in two table

Tags: mysql

I have two table which are joined by primary key ID when i search the i dont get any result.MY code is

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1  JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.id=tb2.user where user ='SUNIL KUMAR'
```

```
Table 1
Id(primary Key)     user    qualification
-----------------------------------------
1         Ramesh Kumar            B.SC
2         Sunil Kumar             MCA
```

```
Table2
user(foreign Key)   Department    City
---------------------------------------
1                 Java            DElhi
2                 Network         Mumbai
```

Comment: can you post the code ?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your database collation, you might need to use the exact case in the WHERE clause i.e. `tbl1.user ='Sunil Kumar'`instead of `tbl1.user ='SUNIL KUMAR'`.
You can also get rid of the case problem with:
`UPPER(tbl1.user) ='SUNIL KUMAR'`

Answer (score 1):

`user` is ambigous, since the column is available in both tables. You would need to prefix it with the table it belongs to.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.id = tb2.user where tbl1.user ='SUNIL KUMAR'
```

Accordingly, you should avoid `select *` and enumarate all the columns that you want to see in the resultset, using column aliases to avoid ambiguity.

---

Side note: beware that the case is different in the table and in your search string. Some RDBMS do case-sensitive comparison, other don't (like MySQL by default). So you are better of fixing this as well:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.id = tb2.user where tbl1.user ='Sunil Kumar'
```

Or (but not index-friendly):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.id = tb2.user where UPPER(tbl1.user) ='SUNIL KUMAR'
```